# Solve $\log(a\times b\div c\times d)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Solve $\log(a\times b\div c\times d)$

At first, I thought the correct answer would be $\log(a)+\log(b)-\log(c)+\log(d)$

But it's actually $\log(a)+\log(b)-(\log(c)+\log(d)) = \log(a)+\log(b)-\log(c)-\log(d)$

So there's some rule about logarithm division that I'm not clear about here. It's not just simply division=subtraction. Can someone explain to me the mistake I made or clarify exactly how the logarithm division rules work and apply it to this case. Thanks.

Comment: the notation $a\times b/c\times d$ is ambigus in the sense that it's not clear if it's $(a\times b)/(c\times d)$ or $\frac{a\times b\times d}{c}$. The "official" solution of your exercise suggest $a\times b/c\times d$ being $(a\times b)/(c\times d)$. If it would have been $\frac{a\times b\times d}{c}$, your solution would have been the correct one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"$a\times b\div c\times d$" is ambiguous. You interpreted it as $(a\times b\times d)\div c$ whereas the person who wrote the solution interpreted it as $(a\times b)\div(c\times d)$. In your case, your answer would be correct. In the person who wrote the solution's case, his solution would also be correct. You should probably clarify with your teacher (or whoever gave the question).

Comment: It’s ambiguous. Ambiguous questions are ambiguous and cannot be answered.

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer to your problem is: “Where do the parentheses go?”

Comment: Isn't that a question...?